# Using Rails 5 attributes api with hash virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a hash store as follows:

```
store :order_details, accessors: %w{item_name, external_id, total......etc}, coder: JSON
```

I'm deserializing this to a ruby object using a lib class elsewhere with a couple of methods in it for validations/operations

I would like to make use of the rails 5 attributes api instead so that I could directly have:

```
attribute :order_details, Type::OrderDetailType.new
```

(plus it would make it easier to add validations to each field in my hash)

I've seen [examples online](https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2016/12/04/introduction-to-activerecord-and-activemodel-attributes-api/) for using rails5's attributes api for simple virtual attributes(strings, integers...etc), but have not come across any info on how to implement it for a hash attribute.
Would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend `Type::OrderDetailType` from `ActiveRecord::Type::Value`

You can override cast and serialize method.

```
def cast(value)
  value
end

def serialize(value)
  value
end
```

An example of `Money` type:

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :price_in_cents, MoneyType.new
end

class MoneyType < ActiveRecord::Type::Integer
  def type_cast(value)
    # convert values like '$10.00' to 1000
  end
end

product = Product.new(price_in_cents: '$10.00')
product.price_in_cents #=> 1000
```

Doc: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html

Example: http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-5-features/

Comment: thanks, also would you know if there is an in-build/recommended way to validate attributes before they are cast/saved (say if `value` was a hash in the above case), apart from validating each key manually in the cast method?

Comment: As per their docs, they are validating inside the cast method only